Ne555 Dimmer using IRFZ44

Excuse me, i am trying to deal with my semi-conductor devices course's assignment of my first year. My topic is that using ne555 and irfz44 to drive a resistive and inductance load like Led or Motor. Desired current about 2A.
I calculated components to run at 1Khz. But do i need a mosfet driver to run IFRZ44 ? Because i checked the data sheet it said ne555 only support about 220mA?

200mA is enough to drive the gate of mosfet directly from 555. I would choose a gate resistor about 100 ohms (120mA  Ig in peak).

Thank you so muchh
